# What kind of "artifact" is a flashlight?

Tags: single-word-requests

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashlight), it used to be referred as a "device". But I'm not sure, I think nowadays the word *device* is used to describe stuff like cameras and mobile phones. What's a generic way to refer to a flashlight? (Just like *device* is used on tablets and smartphones?)

Comment: Depends on how you wish to use it. If you mostly use it for throwing at things and people, then it's a projectile or a missile.

Comment: I'd say it's a device. There's no fundamental difference with a mobile phone, only degrees of complexity.

Comment: "Device" is perfectly valid, and is probably the word I'd pick.

Comment: Every word gets its meaning of relevance from its context and intention.

Comment: Without context, this question is really too broad. Is the word needed for a patent application?  On a sign hanging above the aisle of a hardware store? The category of a murder weapon on a police report?

Comment: It's specifically referred to as an **electrical** device. **Not an electronic device**, which refers to more complex circuitry systems as mentioned in Josh61's answer.

Comment: @Ben - I think you're right; we often qualify the word _device_ with some clue about what the object is used for: _a measuring device, a pollution-control device,_ etc. We might even call a flashlight a _lighting device_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Device](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Device)*** is correct as a generic term to refer to a flashlight:

> - A contrivance or invention serving a particular purpose, especially a machine used ***to perform one or more relatively simple tasks.***
> - (Tools) a machine or tool used for a specific task; contrivance

You may refer to it also as an ***electrical [appliance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appliance)***:

> - any instrument or apparatus for a particular purpose or use.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Hey, how about *tool*?

Comment: Tool is generally used to refer to   an implement, such as a hammer, saw, or spade, that is used by hand, something used to perform and facilitate a manual or a mechanical work. In a very generic sense you could use it, but I prefer the terms I suggested above.